# How to add another field in an existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Okay, I have these table
[image: table1]

and I also have another table right here:

[image]

So,idAlbum is in the gallery table, what is the query for this?
I want to select the data from one field in one table and insert it into a field in another table.

Comment: do you want to select the data from one field in one table and insert it into a field in another table?

Comment: Are you trying to add a column or write a query to join the tables shown? Please elaborate...

Comment: @Vincent Ramdhanie yes, exactly that's what i want to do. done editing my question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to add a field in existing table in PhpMyAdmin, click "Structure" tab while viewing its data, and at the bottom of table structure you have nice box: "Add [number] fields at the [beginning / ending] of a table. Click the button on the right and processd with forms.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
 SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
 FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```