# How to define cakephp mysql index?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin, undefined-index

I am very new to CakePHP and MySQL so I may not know how to properly ask this.
I need to add a payment type radio button to a project I just inherited. 
I added the payment type radio button to the add and edit forms like this:

```
$options = array('check' => 'Check', 'credit' => 'Credit');
$attributes = array('legend' => false);
echo $this->Form->radio('payment', $options, $attributes);
```

The radio button shows up as expected but `payment` is not in the MySQL database so

```
<?php echo h($purchaseOrder['PurchaseOrder']['payment']); ?>
```

causes

> Notice (8): Undefined index: payment
>   [APP\View\PurchaseOrders\view.ctp, line 81]

What is the best way to add `payment` to the database? Is there a way to modify the database without losing existing records?

Comment: Do you *want* to store the payment value? Or is it just a radio button used for changing form inputs and the like?

Comment: I need to save it to the database with the record. It needs to be selected when adding or editing a record and displayed on other views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily a MySQL question rather than CakePHP, if you are able to execute a MySQL Query I would try something like the following (change to your needs):

```
ALTER TABLE purchase_orders ADD COLUMN payment VARCHAR(6);
```

You may benefit from downloading a MySQL tool such as SQLYog or HeidiSQL. If you get the notice after you have added the payment column on a view for example you may want to check the 'fields' parameter on your query (if applicable)

Comment: The project was setup using PhpMyAdmin and a method to add the field is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260040/398460). Thanks a million.